# Remove gap between series in stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, stacked

Is there a way to remove the small white line (gap) between series in a stacked column chart when using Highcharts? See the link below for further understanding.

[The stacked column chart with gaps pointed out](http://postimg.org/image/ygf6pdh4v/)

I have looked into different kinds of padding and other methods but not found anything that works.

Thank you for looking into this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a border, so only what you need is set [borderWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.borderWidth) as 0.